# How to handle Touch event in Augmented reality?

Tags: android, iphone, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to put 5 buttons in layout of Sample Application [Cloud Recognization.](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/cloud-recognition-sample-app)
The buttons appear in two different ways:

1. When tracker is detected, the buttons gets augmented to the tracker.

[image]

2.When camera gets away from the tracker the buttons gets struck to the screen.

[image]

Display is working fine with both the case but touch event of buttons doesn't work for first case (augmented buttons). I need to do different task on each buttons. Common handler as like default CloudReco handler will not work for my case.

So my question is...

1. Can I get button's event handler called in case when button is embedded to tracker.
2. Is there any way to transform user's touch screen-coordinates to button's screen coordinate

Comment: How do you have the buttons defined? in xml? then have an onclick method there?

Comment: but In this sample app they make whole layout as bitmap and pass into native library so we can't define onClick you can see I put link of sample app code(Cloud Recognize). In this app whole layout touchevent available but multiple buttons touch not available

Comment: DId any of you solve this issue finally?

Comment: Guys, is an answer still needed here? You said these are augmented buttons - do you mean these buttons are Vuforia Virtual Buttons, meaning they are drawn as OpenGL textures? If so, in Vuforia's sample you can find how to manage the buttons IDs and how to know which button was tapped.